# POST request doesn't add requested headers in RestTemplate

Tags: java, rest, post, resttemplate

I have to get `User` by sending POST request:

`POST http://myurl.com/rest/user/getbyusername/{user} HTTP/1.0
token: uonIQz8WNE7UB5iR2V0ZYQ==
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0;)
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
Host: myurl.com`

I'm trying to do it using this piece of code:

```
private User getByUsername(String username) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(Params.token);
    headers.put("token", list);
    return restTemplate.postForObject("http://myurl.com/rest/user/getbyusername/{username}", headers, User.class,
            username);
}
```

Controller:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "getbyusername/{username}", 
                produces = "application/json", 
                method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String getByUsername(@PathVariable("username") 
                String username, HttpServletRequest request)
        throws IOException {
    if (!request.getHeader(headerName).isEmpty() && StringUtils.isNotBlank(token)
            && request.getHeader(headerName).equals(token)) {...}
}
```

Sadly the outcome is `Error 404`. Is my code lacking something or am I doing it completely wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set headers like you are currently doing, you will need to wrap your request in a [`HttpEntity`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.html), for example:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("token", Params.token);

HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(username, headers);

restTemplate.postForObject("http://myurl.com/rest/user/getbyusername/{username}",
        entity,
        User.class);
```

This approach is advised in the [`postForObject` Javadocs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-).

Alternatively you could implement a [`ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestInterceptor.html) which would append the `token` header to each request. You would then set this on the `RestTemplate`:

```
restTemplate.setInterceptors(new LinkedList<>(new MyTokenHeaderAddingInterceptor()));
```

This would save you having to remember to send the header for each request.